# Migration of Layout builder enabled node to replace block content

Tags: 8, migrations, layout-builder

I need to iterate through the article nodes that have enabled the layout builder and replace the content block in the layout builder section with a new content block. I need to do this via migration script. But it's not working as expected.

## yaml file

```
uuid: 599162cc-ba3b-4c4d-98c9-404958545305
langcode: en-gb
status: true
dependencies: {  }
_core:
  default_config_hash: lzIn3Lnhv-Efq1Lry7b0-99zKIaAiawY_AHBy_OJPxM
id: migrate_node
class: null
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags: null
migration_group: NAS
label: null
source:
  plugin: get_article_nodes
  key: default
process:
  nid: nid
  uid: uid
  uuid: uuid
  title: title
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  block_type_temp:
    plugin: migrate_node
    source_field: layout_builder_value
  layout_builder__layout:
    plugin: get
    source:
      - '@block_type_temp'
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: article
migration_dependencies: { }
```

## Source plugin

```
<?php


namespace Drupal\my_custom_module\Plugin\migrate\source;

use Drupal\Core\Database\Query\SelectInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Plugin\migrate\source\SqlBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Source plugin for article content.
 *
 * @MigrateSource(
 *   id = "get_article_nodes"
 * )
 */
final class GetArticleNodes extends SqlBase
{

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query(): SelectInterface
  {
    $query = $this->select('node_field_data', 'n');
    $query->fields('n', [
      'nid',
      'vid',
      'type',
      'title',
      'uid',
      'langcode',
      'created',
      'changed',
      'status'
    ]);
    // $query->fields('nlbl', [
    //   'layout_builder__layout_section',
    // ]);
    // $query->leftJoin('node__layout_builder__layout', 'nlbl', 'nlbl.entity_id=n.nid');
    $query->condition('n.type', 'article', '=');
    return $query;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function fields(): array
  {
    $fields = [
      'nid' => $this->t('Node ID'),
      'vid' => $this->t('Vid'),
      'uid' => $this->t('Uid'),
      'title' => $this->t('Title'),
      'type' => $this->t('Type'),
      'created' => $this->t('Created timestamp'),
      'changed' => $this->t('Modified timestamp'),
      'status' => $this->t('Published'),
      'layout_builder__layout_section' => $this->t('Layout builder section'),
    ];

    return $fields;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getIds(): array
  {
    return [
      'nid' => [
        'type' => 'integer',
        'alias' => 'n',
      ],
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function prepareRow(Row $row): bool
  {
    $nid = $row->getSourceProperty('nid');
    $row->setSourceProperty('nid', $nid);

    $result = $this->getDatabase()->query(
      "SELECT bundle , entity_id, layout_builder__layout_section  FROM  node__layout_builder__layout 
      WHERE  entity_id = $nid"
    );
    $layoutbuilder_data = [];
    foreach($result as $record ){
      $layoutbuilder_data[] = $record->layout_builder__layout_section;
    }
    $row->setSourceProperty('layout_builder_value', $layoutbuilder_data);
    return parent::prepareRow($row);
  }
}
```

## Process plugin

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_custom_module\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\layout_builder\Section;
use Drupal\layout_builder\SectionComponent;
use Drupal\migrate\MigrateException;
use Drupal\my_custom_module\LayoutBase;
use Drupal\my_custom_module\LayoutMigrationItem;
use Drupal\my_custom_module\LayoutMigrationMissingBlockException;


/**
 * Custom process plugin for updating layout builder section.
 *
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "migrate_node"
 * )
 */
class MigrateNode extends LayoutBase{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property)
    {
        $nid = $row->getSourceProperty('nid');
        if (!isset($this->configuration['source_field'])) {
            throw new MigrateException('Missing source_field for layout builder process plugin.');
        }
        if($nid == '1429'){ // testing for a single node
          $values = $row->getSourceProperty($this->configuration['source_field']);
          if(isset($values) && is_array($values)){
            foreach($values as $key => $value){
              $sectionComponents = unserialize($value);// am geting section components here
              if ($sectionComponents instanceof Section) {
                $components = $sectionComponents->getComponents();
                foreach ($components as $key => $component) {
                  print_r($component->get('configuration'));
                  // $sectionComponents->insertComponent(1, $component);
                  $configurations = $component->get('configuration');
                  $configurations['id'] = "block_content:3208e4a9-24a2-489c-a0c2-122bcc9c5395"; // this is not working :(
                  $component->setConfiguration($configurations);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Can somebody help me pls?

Answer (score 1):

You return $value but you do not modify it, also please be aware that you use $value as a method argument and as a part of foreach.

You must return a value that is compatible with layout_builder__layout field

e.g. $section in an instance of \Drupal\layout_builder\Section that contains updated components configuration.

```
return [
  'section' => $section,
]
```

or multiple sections

```
return $sections;
```

where $sections is an array that contains multiple sections in the following format:

```
$sections[] = [
  'section' => $section,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @alex. I think i was not sending the correct value, as well as not returning the sections as you said. I resolved it as follows:

```
   /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function transform($value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {
    // Return early if $value is not an array.
    if (!is_array($value)) {
      return NULL;
    }
    foreach ($value as $serializedData) {
      // Unserialize the data.
      $sections = unserialize($serializedData);
      // Check if unserialized data is an instance of Section.
      if ($sections instanceof Section) {
        // Update section components if necessary.
        $this->updateSectionComponents($sections);
      }
      $final_data[] = $sections;
    }
    return $final_data;
  }
    /**
       * Updates section components.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\layout_builder\Section $section
       *   The section object.
       */
      protected function updateSectionComponents(Section $section): void {
        $components = $section->getComponents();
        foreach ($components as $component) {
          // Check if values are instance of SectionComponent.
          if ($component instanceof SectionComponent) {
            // Update the configuration of each component.
            $this->updateComponentConfiguration($component, $section);
          }
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * Updates the configuration of a section component.
       *
       * @param \Drupal\layout_builder\SectionComponent $component
       *   The section component object.
       * @param \Drupal\layout_builder\Section $section
       *   The parent section object.
       */
      protected function updateComponentConfiguration(SectionComponent $component, Section $section): void {
        // Get component configuration.
        $configuration = $component->get('configuration');
        // Query to get new block content (id and uuid) based on revision_id.
        $newBlockIdData = $this->getNewBlockId($configuration['block_revision_id']); // helper function to get old block details
        if (!empty($newBlockIdData)) {
          $attached_block_id = $newBlockIdData[0]->id;
          $old_block_type = $newBlockIdData[0]->type;
          // Old block region.
          $region = $component->get('region');
          // Get new block id.
          $oldBlockData = $this->getOldBlockData($attached_block_id); // helper function to get new block (migrated earlier) from old block id
          if (!empty($oldBlockData) && $configuration['id'] == "inline_block:$old_block_type") {
            // Get new block type.
            $new_block_type = $oldBlockData[0]->bundle;
            // Set the new block id configuration.
            $configuration['id'] = "inline_block:$new_block_type";
            // Create new component.
            $newComponent = (new SectionComponent($this->uuid->generate(), $region, $configuration));
            // Append the new component within the section.
            $section->appendComponent($newComponent);
          }
        }
      }
```